# Replace consecutive substring in string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

I have a string in which a pattern can repeat itself consecutively. My target is to replace one or more consecutive occurrence of the said pattern with just one.

For eg. if string is "BREAKBREAKBREAKword1BREAKword2 word3 BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK word4BREAK word5" and pattern is "BREAK".
Final output should be "BREAKword1BREAKword2 word3 BREAK word4BREAK word5"

Can someone please help me achieve this in python. I'm able to achieve this when pattern is a char but not when it is string. Also, I dont want to implement this using for loops. I was looking for a regex solution.

The regex I have is

```py
re.sub("BREAK{2,}", "BREAK", string).
```

This works when BREAK is just one char but not in string.

Comment: Please include the regex you came up with, then we can help you correct it

Comment: Thank you @DanielFarrell. I was trying something like this re.sub("BREAK{2,}", "BREAK", string).

Comment: just use `re.sub("(BREAK){2,}", "BREAK", string)`. use parenthesis

Comment: `result = re.sub("(?:BREAK)+", "BREAK", subject)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression quantifiers such as `{2,`} quantify the expression they directly follow.  `BREAK{2,}` matches literal `BREA` followed by 2 or more Ks.

```
>>> print(re.match('BREAK{2,}', 'BREAK'))
None
>>> print(re.match('BREAK{2,}', 'BREAKKK'))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1076a2d98>
```

What you're missing here is grouping parentheses.  Enclosing part of a regex in parentheses *groups* that part of the regex together for subsequent quantifiers such as `*`, `+`, `?` , or `{2,}`.

Parentheses also capture the text into numbered variables you can include in the replacement.  You can also name capture groups, or even mark them as a non-capturing group.  But none of that really matters here - just because you end up with a capture group, doesn't mean you have to use it.

```
>>> print(re.sub("(BREAK){2,}", "BREAK", "BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK"))
BREAK
```

Comment: Thank you! This might be a stupid question but how did you convert the background to grey? Can you please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

This replaces multiple occurrences of 'BREAK':

```
subject = 'BREAKBREAKBREAKword1BREAKword2 word3 BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK word4BREAK word5'
result = re.sub('(?:BREAK)+', 'BREAK', subject)
```

This works because `(?:<expression>)+` is a non-capturing group that matches `<expression>` once or more times due to the `+`.